# Run time error after hosting the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error, hosting

I created a website using **C#**. It works perfectly when i run it on my computer. But it **creates a run time error when running it after hosting**. Here i have added a **screenshot** of the error i get.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szww6.png)

Here is the **asp** code

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="surrenderLetterT.aspx.cs" Inherits="Letters_Auto_Generator.surrenderLetterT" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer3" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true"
        Height="1039px" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource2" Width="901px" />
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource2" runat="server">
        <Report FileName="CrystalReport2.rpt">
        </Report>
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the **code** in the **.cs**

```
 public partial class surrenderLetterT : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   DBClass db = new DBClass();
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        string policyNo = Session["PolNo"].ToString();
        string eid = Session["EMPID"].ToString();

        //CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        DataSet printdtls = db.print(policyNo);
        DataSet dsUserInfo = db.getdesignation(eid);

        string Ename = dsUserInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        string Desig = dsUserInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]   ["Designation"].ToString();
        if (printdtls.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ReportDocument myReport = new ReportDocument();
            myReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\CrystalReport2.rpt"));
            myReport.SetDataSource(printdtls.Tables[0]);
            myReport.SetParameterValue("PolicyNo", policyNo);
            myReport.SetParameterValue("Name", Ename);
            myReport.SetParameterValue("designation", Desig);

            CrystalReportViewer3.ReportSource = myReport;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: If it is possible then turn off or set Remote Only Custom Error to see the exact exception

Comment: please turn off custom errors first. so we can really see what the error is. then re-post the screenshot

Comment: This is not the error description, this is the page telling you that your configuration is set to hide the error.

Comment: Can any of you tell me how to turn off or set Remote Only Custom Error?

Comment: i just posted it as an answer, you can find those in your web.config

Answer (score 0):

To *really* show the error please add this line to `system.web` node

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

and this line to `system.webServer` node

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
```

Comment: Please give me another help too. I dont know how to add an image to a comment. How do i do? I have the screen shot of the error after adding your codes

Comment: Sorry but i think it is not possible to add an image to a comment yet. You can just edit your post and post the screenshot there.

Comment: Ok, just now added the new image. Please take a look

Comment: Sorry but we won't be able to know for sure what caused your site to crash with just the screenshot you posted. Though I would suggest searching for **#if DEBUG** lines in your program. Or even access permissions to the database.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it now

Comment: Nothing could find like #if DEBUG.

Comment: Then I suggest looking into the access permissions of your site to the database, and also double checking your connection strings.

Comment: Access permission is fine. Because other functions work without any problem. Only this reoprt create error